# Visualisation of relative site sizes

Tags: discussion, statistics

I wonder if anyone has done any quick one-off treemaps comparing the relative sizes of the different Stack Exchange sites, based on the number of questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A somewhat different take on the comparison: number of questions vs traffic to the sites.  Color-coded according to SE classification of sites: Technology (blue), Science (red), Culture & Recreation (green), Life & Arts (magenta), Business (black), Professional (black). Data from May 2014, log-log plot.

[image: 2D diagram]

From [Hertzsprung–Russell diagram of Stack Exchange sites](http://calculus7.org/2014/05/03/hertzsprung-russell-diagram-of-stack-exchange-sites/)

Comment: While this answer doesn't satisfy *my unstated* needs (I wanted to see how much influence Skeptics.SE has on the overall domain - the lack of labels and the log-scale make it less useful for that), I am impressed at how well it addressed a question that had been specifically written for my answer, and that it squeezes information into the second dimension too. I have to reward it with the Accepted tick.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think it's the magenta dot on the left edge of the spectrum, at 10^4 visits/day mark. Also, [xkcd1246](http://xkcd.com/1246/).

Answer (score 9):

Why, I am glad you asked! As a matter of fact, I just produced one purely out of curiousity:

Data extracted 11-July-2014.
Based on number of questions (only) of non-meta sites.
Click to embiggen.

[image: Tree Map of all sites]

Obviously Stack Overflow dominates, so if we filter that out:

[image: Tree Map of all sites except SO]

Comment: At least you should write "I am glad *I* asked". ;-)